# BUG: Dask K-means Exception heppen Too many indices for array

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed, dask-ml

I am using K-means clustering on a dataset with shape (563, 207383) via Dask-K-means (CPU based), and am getting the following error:

"Dask K-means Exception heppen Too many indices for array"

But when I use RapidsAI dask_k-means (GPU Based) it works fine on the same dataset.
Could there be a bug in Dask-Kmeans, or do I need to set some configurations before using it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This problem arises with dask (2021.3.0), while with dask (2021.1.1)  code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Upgrade to 2021.04.0 solved the issue.